# inline adding rows in jqgrid version 4.4.4

Tags: jquery, jqgrid-asp.net, free-jqgrid, inline-editing

I'm trying to add a new row inline in free jggrid version 4.13.5 but I cannot get it to work. 
Inline edit works but inline adding row doesn't. This is the code for inline editing.I'm trying to give editing and adding options inside a sub-grid. Also, the icons for add, delete and edit do not appear. There's the references.

```
    <link href="~/Content/ui.jqgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/jquery.custom/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom-jquery-        ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/free-jqGrid/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/free-jqGrid/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/cashjqgridinternal.js"></script>
```

Cashjggridinternal.js

```
    $(function () {
debugger;
var eXids = [];
function RefreshGridData() {
    var num;
    eXids = new Array();
    $("#grid tr:has(.sgexpanded)").each(function () {
        num = $(this).attr('OutputcashID');
        eXids.push(num);
    });
    $("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");
};
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    url: "/OutputCashInternal/GetValues",
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'Get',
    //table header name 
    colNames: ['OutputcashID', 'Level1', 'Level2', 'LoadID', 'ServerName', 'GroupID', 'InternalAccountRef', 'ExternalAccountRef', 'InternalLocalAmt', 'ExternalLocalAmt', 'TotalRecitems', 'TotalReconcilingItems', 'LocalDifference', 'UnreconcileDifference'],
    //colModel takes the data from controller and binds to grid 
    colModel: [
        { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'OutputcashID', index: 'OutputcashID', editable: false },
        { key: false, name: 'Fund', index: 'Fund', editable: false },
        { key: false, name: 'Custodian', index: 'Custodian', editable: false },
        { key: false, hidden: true, name: 'LoadID', index: 'LoadID', editable: false },
        { key: false, hidden: true, name: 'ServerName', index: 'ServerName', editable: false },
        { key: false, hidden: true, name: 'GroupID', index: 'GroupID', editable: false },
        { key: false, name: 'InternalAccountRef', index: 'InternalAccountRef', editable: false },
        { key: false, name: 'ExternalAccountRef', index: 'ExternalAccountRef', editable: false },
        { key: false, name: 'InternalLocalAmt', index: 'InternalLocalAmt', editable: false },
        { key: false, name: 'ExternalLocalAmt', index: 'ExternalLocalAmt', editable: false },
        { key: false, name: 'TotalRecitems', index: 'TotalRecitems', editable: false },
        { key: false, name: 'TotalReconcilingItems', index: 'TotalReconcilingItems', editable: false },
        { key: false, name: 'LocalDifference', index: 'LocalDifference', editable: false },
        { key: false, name: 'UnreconcileDifference', index: 'UnreconcileDifference', editable: false },
    ],
    loadonce: true,
    pager: $('#pager'),
    rowNum: 20,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
    height: '100%',
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: 'OutputCash For Internal User',
    emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
    jsonReader: {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: false,
        Id: "0"
    },
    autowidth: true,
    scrollerbar: true,
    height: 200,
    multiselect: false,
    subGrid: true,
    subGridRowExpanded: function (subgrid_id, row_id) {
        // we pass two parameters
        // subgrid_id is a id of the div tag created whitin a table data
        // the id of this elemenet is a combination of the "sg_" + id of the row
        // the row_id is the id of the row
        // If we wan to pass additinal parameters to the url we can use
        // a method getRowData(row_id) - which returns associative array in type name-value
        // here we can easy construct the flowing
        var subgrid_table_id, pager_id;
        subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id + "_t";
        pager_id = "p_" + subgrid_table_id;
        var pLoadID = $("#grid").jqGrid('getCell', row_id, 'LoadID');
        var pGroupID = $("#grid").jqGrid('getCell', row_id, 'GroupID');
        var pEditData = { "LoadID": pLoadID, "GroupID": pGroupID };
        $("#" + subgrid_id).html("<table id='" + subgrid_table_id + "' class='scroll'></table><div id='" + pager_id + "' class='scroll'></div>");
        $("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
            url: "/OutputCashInternal/GetData?sid=" + row_id,
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'Get',
            //table header name 
            colNames: ['OutputCashUpdatedID', 'LoadID', 'GroupID', 'ExternalAccountRef', 'InternalLocalAmtAdded', 'ExternalLocalAmtAdded', 'TransactionComments', 'InternalComments', 'ClientCommnets'],
            //colModel takes the data from controller and binds to grid 
            colModel: [
                { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'OutputCashUpdatedID', index: 'OutputCashUpdatedID', editable: true },
                { key: false, hidden: true, name: 'LoadID', index: 'LoadID', editable: false },
                { key: false, hidden: true, name: 'GroupID', index: 'GroupID', editable: false },
                { key: false, name: 'ExternalAccountRef', index: 'ExternalAccountRef', editable: false },
                { key: false, name: 'InternalLocalAmtAdded', index: 'InternalLocalAmtAdded', editable: true },
                { key: false, name: 'ExternalLocalAmtAdded', index: 'ExternalLocalAmtAdded', editable: true },
                { key: false, name: 'Comments', index: 'Comments', editable: true },
                { key: false, name: 'Comment1', index: 'Comment1', editable: true },
                { key: false, name: 'Comment2', index: 'Comment2', editable: true, editoptions: { readonly: "readonly" } },
            ],
            //loadonce: false,
            rowNum: 20,
            pager: pager_id,
            sortname: 'Fund',
            sortorder: "asc",
            height: '100%',
            jsonReader: {
                root: "rows",
                page: "page",
                total: "total",
                records: "records",
                repeatitems: false,
                Id: "0"
            }
        });
        $("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid', '#' + pager_id, {

            edit: false,
            add: false,
            del: false,
            search: false,


        }
    );

        var editparameters = {
            keys: false,
            oneditfunc: null,
            url: '/OutputCashInternal/Edit',
            successfunc: function (val) {
                if (val.responseText != "") {
                    alert(val.responseText);
                }
                $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
            },
            extraparam: {
                rowid: function () {
                    var sel_id = $("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                    var value = $("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, '_id');
                    return value;
                }
            },
            aftersavefunc: null,
            errorfunc: null,
            afterrestorefunc: null,
            restoreAfterError: true,
            mtype: "POST"

        }


        var saveparameters = {
            useDefValues: true,
            url: '/OutputCashInternal/Create',            
            extraparam: {},
            mtype: "POST"               
        }

        var parameters = {
            edit: true,
            editicon: "ui-icon-pencil",
            add: true,
            addicon: "ui-icon-plus",
            save: true,
            saveicon: "ui-icon-disk",
            cancel: true,
            cancelicon: "ui-icon-cancel",
            addParams:{ addRowParams: saveparameters },
            editParams: editparameters

        };

        $("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('inlineNav', '#' + pager_id, parameters);

    },

    subGridRowColapsed: function (subgrid_id, row_id) {
        // this function is called before removing the data
        //var subgrid_table_id;
        //subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
        //jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).remove();
    },
    //pager-you have to choose here what icons should appear at the bottom
    //like edit,create,delete icons
    gridComplete: function () {
        for (var j = 0; j < eXids.length; j = j + 1) {
            $("#grid").jqGrid('expandSubGridRow', eXids[j]);
        }
    },
}).navGrid('#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: true, refresh: true })
    });
```

This the controller:

```
    public string Create(OutputCashUpdated obj)
    {
        string msg;
        try
        {
            //if (ModelState.IsValid)
            //{
            //db2.Entry(newOCU).State = EntityState.Modified;
            OutputCashUpdated newOCU = new OutputCashUpdated();
            OutputCash newOC = db2.OutputCashes.Single(s => s.LoadID == obj.LoadID && s.GroupID == obj.GroupID); // && c.AsOfDate == newOCU.AsOfDate);
            db2.OutputCashUpdateds.Add(newOCU);
            newOCU.LoadID = newOC.LoadID;
            newOCU.GroupID = newOC.GroupID;
            newOCU.AsOfDate = newOC.AsOfDate;
            newOCU.AppClientID = newOC.AppClientID;

            newOCU.InternalLocalAmtAdded = obj.InternalLocalAmtAdded;
            newOCU.ExternalLocalAmtAdded = obj.ExternalLocalAmtAdded;
            newOCU.Comments = obj.Comments;
            newOCU.Comment1 = obj.Comment1;
            newOCU.Comment2 = obj.Comment2;
            db2.SaveChanges();
            var CountReconcileItems = db2.OutputCashUpdateds.Count(w => w.LoadID == newOC.LoadID && w.GroupID == newOC.GroupID && w.AsOfDate == newOC.AsOfDate);
            var SumReconcileExternalItems = db2.OutputCashUpdateds.Where(w => w.LoadID == newOC.LoadID && w.GroupID == newOC.GroupID && w.AsOfDate == newOC.AsOfDate).Sum(s => s.ExternalLocalAmtAdded).GetValueOrDefault(0);
            var SumReconcileInternalItems = db2.OutputCashUpdateds.Where(w => w.LoadID == newOC.LoadID && w.GroupID == newOC.GroupID && w.AsOfDate == newOC.AsOfDate).Sum(s => s.InternalLocalAmtAdded).GetValueOrDefault(0);
            var SumReconcileItems = SumReconcileExternalItems + SumReconcileInternalItems;
            newOC.TotalRecitems = CountReconcileItems;
            newOC.TotalReconcilingItems = SumReconcileItems;
            newOC.UnreconcileDifference = newOC.LocalDifference - newOC.TotalReconcilingItems;
            db2.SaveChanges();
            msg = "Saved Successfully";
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    msg = "Validation data not successfull";
            //}
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg = "Error occured:" + ex.Message;
        }
        return msg;
    }
```

The error I get is that there are no sequence elements but on debugging I can see that the elements are passed. So I'm unable to find out where it's going wrong. Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You wrote "Inline edit works but inline row doesn't". What you mean? What is not work? Is inline editing work or not? I recommend you to add `idPrefix` in all subgrids. Moreover, the retro version 4.4.4 of jqGrid is almost 4 years old. Is it really required to use? I suggest you to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.5, which you can use directly from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) and [the code example](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#type_of_data_code)).

Comment: @Oleg: I updated my solution, I uninstalled 4.4.4 and used 4.13.5. My issue is when I'm doing an inline edit, the data is successfully saved but i'm not able to do inline add. I don't know where I'm going wrong. Also, now the icons for add, delete or edit do not appear. I don't know if that's the issue with my script libraries or if there's some issue with the code.

Comment: @oleg:The issue with creating a new row and adding data is when it hits the create action of the controller, it passes null values for load Id and group id. I want to pass the load id and group id for the parent row, in cashgridinternal.js, I want to pass this variable        var pEditData = { "LoadID": pLoadID, "GroupID": pGroupID }; , so I put editData:pEditData, in save parameters, I don't know if that's the right way of doing it but it still doesn't work.

Comment: After migration to free jqGrid you have many possibilities to simplify your code and to use new possibilities. You can use `editable: "hidden"` instead of `editable: false` for the columns `LoadID` and `GroupID`.

Comment: @Oleg: How do i pass loadId and groupid through the add method? Putting editData: pEditData in addParams doesn't work. It's passing null values and that's why I'm getting an error.

Comment: I wrote you before in the previous comment: you should just replace the property `editable: false` to `editable: "hidden"` in `colModel` for the columns `LoadID` and `GroupID`. The string value `"hidden"` of the `editable` property means **sending the contains of the column to the server during editing**, but holding the column non-editable for the user. One can use the property for either hidden of visible columns. By the way I recommend you to remove unneeded `key: false`, `editable: false` and all `index` properties from `colModel`. Including of such properties do nothing.

Comment: @Oleg: I tried what you asked me to do. I changed it to hidden but it still doesn't pass the values to the create action in the controller. Yes, I'll remove those properties. Thanks. Instead of inline I displayed form and that I was able to do successfully but the requirement is to do it inline. Anything else that I can try?

Comment: Itpically, one don't see his own errors. I'm sure that you did not what I suggested you. You wrote "I changed it to hidden", but I suggested you to use of `editable: "hidden"` instead of `editable: false`. About other suggestions: I'm sure that you can reduce your code essentially, but I don't know the format of the data returned from `/OutputCashInternal/GetValues` and `"/OutputCashInternal/GetData?sid=" + row_id`. Typically `jsonReader` is not needed. One can use Font Awesome (see [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#type_of_data_code)) and so on.

Comment: @oleg: Sorry I do not communicate clearly. What I meant was I changed editable:false to editable:hidden. I will reduce the code but I want to implement the functionality first.

Comment: Could you provide the demo (in jsfiddle for example), which has the problem, which you describe? I could fix it. You can use Echo service of JSFiddle to simulate any requests to the server. You can et https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/xfpkp20y/ as the basis and modify it to the code, which reproduces the problem.